# App crashes on screen rotation when android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog is displayed and screen is rotated

Tags: android, dialog

I have read all the related questions to this problem and tried everything (including using `setRetainInstance`) and have not managed to find anything that works. I pared my dialogFragment to the bone (see below) and I still have the problem. Having read a blog elsewhere in which the author states he has tried everything on StackOverflow without success, I have decided to do as he did and dismiss the dialogFragment in onStop and recreate it in onStart. However I thought I would ask in case there is a new solution to this problem.

Debugging in Android Studio I just receive an unfortunately the app has stopped message, There is not trapped exception and no logcat output.

Here is the much reduced code that still fails:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class TextViewDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    public TextViewDialogFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    static public TextViewDialogFragment newInstance(int title, @Nullable String message, int identifier, int inputType, int positiveText, int negativeText, boolean cancelable)
    {
        TextViewDialogFragment fragement = new TextViewDialogFragment();
        return fragement;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Using AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity(); does not help.
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alert.setCancelable(true).setTitle("title");
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

I create and show the dialog from an `AppCompatActivity` with the following code:

```
folderAddGetName = TextViewDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.add_folder, resources.getString(R.string.addFolderMessage, selectedFolderView.getText()), 1, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES, R.string.add, android.R.string.cancel, true);
folderAddGetName.show(getFragmentManager(), "addFolder");
```

Comment: What is the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the error to an error in the activity that was only encountered when the dialogfragment had been created. The dialog fragment was in fact ok.

Comment: Really, you should provide more details. The code you've been posted works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.app.DialogFragment` if you using `AppCompatActivity`. Also use `folderAddGetName.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "addFolder");`